# adding custom js to magento cms page

Tags: magento

I would really like to use this on a single cms page in magento. For some reason it will not show the content. i allready tried several google answers without any succes.

[Smartphone kopen](http://smartphone-kopen.nl/daisycon)    link to page with script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
mediaid=191156;subid='';entry=25;provider='0';duration=0;renewal=0;daisyconTelecomFilterView=1;col='1111111';programs='all';header='FFFFFF';background_price='E2F0FB';border='ECECEC';button_text='Bekijken';button_color='FF8300';button_hover='FF9E3D';button_textcolor='FFFFFF';font='Arial';slider='3694C7';minMob='0';maxMob='1000';minMin='100';maxMin='3000';minInt='200';maxInt='6000';minAb='0';maxAb='100';mobiles='all';
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post what you tried and what didn't work about it.

Comment: where did you add this? In the content section of the cms page?

Comment: design tab of cms page,  Layout Update XML field

Answer (score 1):

Edit your page, in design tab add

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js</script>
    </action>
    <block type="core/text" name="custom.js" >
        <action method="setText">
            <text>// <![CDATA[mediaid=191156;subid='';entry=25;provider='0';duration=0;renewal=0;daisyconTelecomFilterView=1;col='1111111';programs='all';header='FFFFFF';background_price='E2F0FB';border='ECECEC';button_text='Bekijken';button_color='FF8300';button_hover='FF9E3D';button_textcolor='FFFFFF';font='Arial';slider='3694C7';minMob='0';maxMob='1000';minMin='100';maxMin='3000';minInt='200';maxInt='6000';minAb='0';maxAb='100';mobiles='all'; // ]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/general.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/jquery.nouislider.min.js</script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Sorry, now tested adn working code

Comment: That does not make it work, if i paste above in Layout Update XML on design tab there's still no script showing up

Comment: Still not working after tested code, still got white page.  pasted link in first post!

Comment: interesting, maybe it's cache issue, clear it for layouts and blocks output

Comment: If you take a look at the link in first post u will see the script text above the header.

Comment: This is perfect for the analytics experiments feature.